# Continuously playing random video on a page without repeating

Tags: javascript, html

I have created some code which allows me to see 2 different videos. When the code runs it automatically picks one of them. I want to make it so that once one of them is picked at random when the page refreshes, but exclude the video that was last played.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var videos = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1"];
        window.onload = function () {
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
            var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            var randomVideoUrl = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
            player.setAttribute('width', '640');
            player.setAttribute('height', '390');
            player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
            playerDiv.appendChild(player);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="random_player" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Save the index of the chosen element in a `sessionStorage` and play the other one if a value in the session exists

Comment: Use cookies or localStorage to persist the index of the video played before reload.

Comment: How will i be able to do that are you able to give a demonstration please

Comment: @empiric Are you able to show a demonstration since I really need one please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var videos = [
      {id:1 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=0"},
      {id:2 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1"}
  ];
  window.onload = function () {
      var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
      var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      var previousId = localStorage.getItem('previousId');
      if(previousId) {
          var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
          videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
      }
      var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
      localStorage.setItem('previousId', videos[current].id);
      localStorage.getItem('previousId');
      var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
      player.setAttribute('width', '640');
      player.setAttribute('height', '390');
      player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
      playerDiv.appendChild(player);
  };
```

Comment: It works perfectly and if i need to add more videos should i just make it in a id and thats it

Answer (score 2):

> How will i be able to do that are you able to give a demonstration
>   please

**EDIT:**
We need an id because the indexes change if we splice the array:

```js
var videos = [
  {id:1 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1"},
  {id:2 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1"}
];
window.onload = function () {
  var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
  var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  var previousId = localStorage.getItem('previousId');
  if(previousId) {
    var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
    videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
  }
  var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  localStorage.setItem('previousId', videos[current].id);
  var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
  player.setAttribute('width', '640');
  player.setAttribute('height', '390');
  player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
  playerDiv.appendChild(player);
};
```

Comment: Depending on the use case you could use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` as that will be cleared when e.g. the browser window is closes. `localStorage` persists until manually deleted

Comment: I tried it and it worked after the first refresh but it didn't work afterwards

Comment: I just changed it to session storage and im keep getting the same problem after first refresh it changes back to the dice over and over and over

Comment: Im still getting the same issue im not sure why

Comment: After your code this is what i have is this correct                                                                       </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="random_player" />
</body>

</html>

Comment: ... ok bro ... i will test and debug that for you here .... just give me a minute

Comment: I want it so that after the video 1 is played randomly then the video 2 is 100% to play the second time i refresh and then so on....

Comment: I know .... better you undestand the underlying concept then you can debug yourself ... but anyways its tested now and works as expected

Comment: @Mischa Thanks works like a charm but if i needed to add more videos will i just put it in a Id and thats it pretty much

Comment: depends on what you want?!? if u want to go to the next item in the list on every reload? ... then no. ... its just preventing to play the same video after reload again not iterating through the list.

Comment: Ok so say if i wanted to go through a list will i need to do it in a different way?